# Module compiled with Swift 5.5.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.5.2 compiler RazorPay

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm working on a Flutter app, when trying to build the iOS version on xCode it's showing me this error

```
Module compiled with Swift 5.5.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.5.2 compiler
```

I updated my Pods folder, deleted profile.lock, deleted Derived Data folder, Cleaned my Build folder .. and still got same error

I even changed the Runner -> Target -> Build Settings -> Build Libraries for Distribution to YES, and still doesn't work

I remember i faced this issue before and fixed it, but really forgot what i did :/

What shall i do please?

[image]

Comment: Hey @Ahmed hay fix this issue?
I am facing same issue can you please help me out?

Comment: hi @museerAhamadAnsari yes please check the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding this code into my Podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
  end
end
```